# extracting list of longs from database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an object that contains a list of longs. In the database, I'm storing this as a string separated with commas. Whenever I do a read/write operation, I'm always exploding or joining this string and I'm looking to move this step from the business logic to the queries. So this is what I tried with my query:

```
var TheData = (from l in MyDC.Table
               ....
               select new MyModel()
               {
                   TheListOfLongs = (from x in l.StringOfLongs.Split(',')
                                     select Convert.ToInt64(x)).ToList<long>(),

                    SomeObjectProp = ...

               }).ToList();
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' has no supported translation to
>   SQL.

How can I fix my query to make it work?

Comment: Can you post enough code to compile/reproduce the issue? Or can you post the `Model` class?

Comment: @RyanGates: public List<long> TheListOfLongs { get; set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var TheData = MyDC.Table
                  .Where(...)
// optionally     .Select(l => new { l.StringOfLongs, l.SomeObjectProp })
                  .AsEnumerable() // move execution to memory
                  .Select(l => new Model() {
                      TheListOfLongs = l.StringOfLongs.Split(',')
                                        .Select(x => Int64.Parse(x))
                                        .ToList(),
                      SomeObjectProp = l.SomeObjectProp
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works: I'm getting a list of MyModel and one of the properties is a list of longs, stored in the db as a string of comma separated values. How do I retrieve all the other properties?

Comment: @frenchie when I wrote answer, there was no `SomeObjectProp` in question. Now I updated the answer

Comment: ok, I see what you're doing. I initially wrote the query in query syntax. Is there any way to fix the query the way I had it written? If not then no problem, I'll take your answer. Also, there's an orderby l.SomeField descending that I didn't include in the question because it didn't seem relevant.

Comment: @frenchie when you doing `ToList()` then you have to mix query and method syntax. And I think that looks not very pretty :)

Comment: You shouldn't use `ToList` to convert an `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable`.  Just use `AsEnumerable`.  It will ensure that any subsequent LINQ queries use Linq to objects, not the query provider, but don't eagerly evaluate the query or needlessly pull the entire data set into memory.

Comment: Oh, and you may want to place an additional `Select` right after the `Where` to select `StringOfLongs` and `SomeObjectProp` so that all of the fields that you don't need aren't brought over from the database.

Comment: @Servy, yes I thought about that select, but decided not to use it, because OP asked for other properties as well. Are you sure `AsEnumerable` is not same as simple casting to `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It's exactly the same as casting to `IEnumerable`.  That's all it does, and that's exactly what you want to do.  You could use a cast instead, but you'd lose the fluent syntax.  That's exactly why `AsEnumerable` was created to begin with.  This is basically it's sole purpose in life.

Comment: @Servy ah I see now - with IEnumerable you call GetEnumerator on ObjectResult, which cases query to be executed. Very good hint, thanks again

Comment: @lazyberezovsky This is the entire implementation of the method: `public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {return source;}`.  It does not call `GetEnumerator` within the call to the method.

Comment: Be aware that while this solution may achieve the desired results, the performance will degrade as you are essentially filtering on the client rather than on the server.

Comment: @JimWooley Not really.  The database can't do this mapping any more efficiently than your computer can.  Now if you are adding a `Where` or `Join` operation *after* this call then I agree, it would be much more effective if done on the DB side.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky See [Jon's Edulinq article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable.aspx) for more info on `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: @Servy I understand that. I talked about deeper things. On the EF implementation DbSet > DbQuery > InternalQuery > ObjectQuery > ObjectResults. See `GetEnumerator` method there

Comment: @lazyberezovsky `IQueryable` extends `IEnumerable`, so any `IQueryable` type can be cast to an `IEnumerable through an *implicit* cast.  That's what's going on here.  When you call `AsEnumerable` there is an *implicit* cast from the `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Servy take a look *deeper* with reflector :) I'm not talking about casting, I'm talking about implementaion

Answer (score 3):

you're attempting to execute the Split operation on the DB, which replies by saying 'I have no idea how to do what you just asked me to do!'.

The solution is to call `.ToList()` before you `select new Model()`
EDIT: rework and modifications for deferment - accidentally moved split to wrong place - should be right now

```
var TheData = (from l in MyDC.Table select new { 
    stringLong = l.StringOfLongs,
    OtherProps = //...
})
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(x => new Model 
                   { 
                       TheListOfLongs = x.stringLong 
                              .Split(',')   
                              .Select(y => Convert.ToInt64(y)
                              .Cast<long>(),
                       OtherProps = // ...
                   });
```

If you want this all in query syntax, it would look like so:

```
var TheData = (from l in MyDC.Table select new { 
    stringLong = l.StringOfLongs,
    OtherProps = //...
}).AsEnumerable();

var RealTheData = (from l in TheData select new Model 
    {
        TheListOfLongs = (from s in l.stringLong 
                              .Split(',') select Convert.ToInt64(s).Cast<long>(),
                       OtherProps = // ...
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that TheListOfLongs is just one of the fields I'm getting from the DB, that's why I'm callig ToList() at the end: I'm retrieving a list of MyModel()

Comment: check my edits it's an example not intended to be prod-capable =)

Comment: happy? I put back the `.Select` I accidentally removed earlier

Comment: why would that make me happy? Glad you made your code compilable. If you will remove useless `Cast<long>` it will be event better

Comment: You shouldn't use `ToList` to convert an `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable`.  Just use `AsEnumerable`.  It will ensure that any subsequent LINQ queries use Linq to objects, not the query provider, but don't eagerly evaluate the query or needlessly pull the entire data set into memory.

Comment: @Servy - `AsEnumerable` will execute the DB query same as `ToList` will, with the same resulting SQL statement. What do you mean "don't eagerly evaluate the query..."?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - my code was intended to demonstrate a possible way the OP could "Fix [his] my query" as well as complement the explanation of why his query wasn't working to begin with. I generally prefer to teach a man to fish over handing him a tuna sandwich :)

Comment: @JoshE Well, first off, no, it won't.  `AsEnumerable` won't execute the query until the results are iterated; it defers execution.  Second, it avoids pulling the entire result set into memory and instead allows the items to be brought in one at a time, streaming them.  Finally, the list is never used, it's just iterated, so the list of references is just wasting memory needlessly.

Comment: @Servy - nvm I understand what you're saying, but that will still mean that L2S will try to translate the `.Split` method call expression tree node into a SQL statement, and fail

Comment: @JoshE That's not the case.  By calling `AsEnumerable` the variable returned will be of type `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IQueryable<T>`, which means it will use the `Enumerable` LINQ methods and not the `Queryable` LINQ methods, meaning it will be doing LINQ to objects, not LINQ to SQL, or whatever the query provider is.  It's a way of saying, "From now on use the LINQ to objects methods instead of the query methods, but still defer execution until I'm iterated."  Which is *exactly* what you want in this context.

Comment: right, all you've done is change when the InvalidOperationException gets thrown to whenever the list is iterated. There still has to be *some* point where a DB query is issued, and if the query expression has a `.Split` call in it at that time, *the entire query will still fail*

Comment: @JoshE No, it wont'.  Try it yourself if you don't believe me.  If you call `AsEnumerable` before the `Select` that contains the split then the `Select` won't use the `IQueryable` overload; it won't pass in an `Expression<Func<T1,T2>>` it will pass in a `Func<T1,T2>` and use the `Enumerable` class's definition of `Select` instead, thus executing the `Split` in the C# code instead of in the database.

Comment: @JoshE See [Jon's Edulinq article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable.aspx) for more info on `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: @Servy - well I stand corrected! Wonder why that aspect isn't mentioned in very many (if any) places in the documentation. It seems like a pretty big thing, 'specially since so much ado is made in tutorials etc about deferred execution and such

Comment: @JoshE It's discussed in the MSDN page for `AsEnumerable` in the remarks section: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx).  `"A Table type that represents a database table could have a Where method that takes the predicate argument as an expression tree and converts the tree to SQL for remote execution. If remote execution is not desired, for example because the predicate invokes a local method, the AsEnumerable<TSource> method can be used to hide the custom methods and instead make the standard query operators available."`  That's *exactly* what you're trying to do.